# Best way to find element in an array size in thousands JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, search, optimization

I need to verify serial number each time user enters it, search is 1 out of possibly hundred thousands. Liner solution would be I get the entire list with one call when the app is loaded initially and then perform a linear search per serial number, but that could be a lengthy process since a user can enter up to 150 serial number at a time.

Is there another way to perform search better?

The array is unsorted
Serial number is always length of 12 and mix of chars and numbers.

Comment: Make an index. Create an object that has the serial numbers as keys.

Comment: We'll need more information. Where is the data from? Is a backend involved? Do you interface with an API? Is this done over the network? What JavaScript runtime is this (node, browser, electron, etc.)?

Comment: Also this seems like something that would be far more appropriate to do in the database at your server application. Sending a list of hundreds of thousands of things to the client seems kind-of insane.

Comment: Thank you @Pointy that would be insane. totally not preferred.

Comment: @Joseph yes, backend is involved, all done over the network, NODE

Comment: array = new Set(array); array.has(serial); is not good enough?

Comment: @syduki it can work but if there is a way to eliminate backend sending me the huge list would be ideal.

Comment: Why not send a serial number to backend and let backend respond if it is unique or not. Why fetch list of all serial numbers and do check at front end?